# How do I take the contraction of an ideal which is not in the image of the given morphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If I have a morphism of rings $\phi: A \to B$ which is not surjective, how should I take the preimage of an ideal not contained in the image of $\phi$?

Comment: The same way you take the preimage of anything.

Comment: If $J$ is an ideal of $B$, then $\phi^{-1}(J)$ is defined regardless of whether $\phi$ is surjective. It happens to be the same as $\psi^{-1}(\phi(A)\cap J)$, where $\psi$ is the morphism from $A$ to $\phi(A)$ induced by $\phi$.

Comment: @Seth as embarrassing as it is, I've never gone over this...

Comment: @user1876508 ok, sorry, if that came across as rude.  I wrote an answer.

Comment: @Seth thank you for the answer. I appreciate your apology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi:A\to B$ be any function between sets and $I$ any subset of $B$.  Then $\phi^{-1}(I)$ is defined as the set of all $a\in A$ such that $\phi (a) \in I$.

In your case you just need to show that if $A$ and $B$ are rings, $I$ an ideal of $B$, and $\phi$ a ring homomorphism, that $\phi^{-1}(I)$ is an ideal of $A$.  Then the definition makes sense.